# Upload image with an in-memory stream to input using Pillow + WebDriver?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm getting an Image from URL with Pillow, and creating an stream (BytesIO/StringIO).

```
r = requests.get("http://i.imgur.com/SH9lKxu.jpg")
stream = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
```

Since I want to upload this image using an `<input type="file" />` with selenium WebDriver. I can do something like this to upload a file:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("PATH_TO_IMAGE")
```

I would like to know If its possible to upload that image from a stream without having to mess with files / file paths... I'm trying to avoid filesystem Read/Write. And do it in-memory or as much with temporary files. I'm also Wondering If that stream could be encoded to Base64, and then uploaded passing the string to the send_keys function you can see above :$

PS: Hope you like the image :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking multiple questions here.

---

First, how do you convert a a JPEG without downloading it to a file? You're already doing that, so I don't know what you're asking here.

---

Next, "And do it in-memory or as much with temporary files." I don't know what this means, but you can do it with temporary files with the `tempfile` library in the stdlib, and you can do it in-memory too; both are easy.

---

Next, you want to know how to do a streaming upload with `requests`. The easy way to do that, as explained in [Streaming Uploads](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads), is to "simply provide a file-like object for your body". This can be a tempfile, but it can just as easily be a `BytesIO`. Since you're already using one in your question, I assume you know how to do this.

(As a side note, I'm not sure *why* you're using `BytesIO(r.content)` when requests already gives you a way to use a response object as a file-like object, and even to do it by streaming on demand instead of by waiting until the full content is available, but that isn't relevant here.)

If you want to upload it with selenium instead of requests… well then you *do* need a temporary file. The whole point of selenium is that it's scripting a web browser. You can't just type a bunch of bytes at your web browser in an upload form, you have to select a file on your filesystem. So selenium needs to fake you selecting a file on your filesystem. This is a perfect job for `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`.

---

Finally, "I'm also Wondering If that stream could be encoded to Base64".

Sure it can. Since you're just converting the image in-memory, you can just encode it with, e.g., `base64.b64encode`. Or, if you prefer, you can wrap your `BytesIO` in a `codecs` wrapper to base-64 it on the fly. But I'm not sure why you want to do that here.

Comment: I was not asking about format conversion. Just If would be possible to convert/encode that stream in any way to upload the image through an `<input type='file' />`. I MUST use WebDriver for this task so I think my best bet will be to use the tempfile of stdlib. Excuse me for that strange question, I'm very new to python and english isn't my first lang (sadly). It was helpful anyway. I'll mark it as answered. Thank you !